# class.getResource returns a wrong path of my file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2

I want to use Velocity to template my emails, but i struggled to give the right path of my template : "template.vm" that in my resource folder created by maven.

I used : class.getResource("template.vm").getPath => but getResource retruns null wich is logique cause as i know template.vm in that case should be in the same package of the class, and my template.vm is on WEB-INF/classes

So i used : class.getResource("/template.vm").getPath, but it returns a wrong path, in my case  the path of template.vm is : D:/folderOne/FolderTwo/WEB-INF/classes/template.vm   and getResource retruns : /D:/folderOne/FolderTwo/WEB-INF/classes/template.vm   what makes velocity class to throw : Unable to find resource with the given path : /D:/folderOne/FolderTwo/WEB-INF/classes/template.vm

I am struggling with this little probleme more then a day now, please help.

Comment: Why do you need the path?  Can't you just use the inputstream?

Comment: I need the path to give it to velocity methode to load the template, i use velocity like this : Template t = VelocityEngine.getTemplate(String name) when name is the name of the template : template.vm

Comment: @BadrDRAIFI its happening because u are tring to get the path from context, try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream

Comment: @AkashYadav i tried that, but the always the same problem ResourceNotFoundException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [ClassPathResourceLoader](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/runtime/resource/loader/ClasspathResourceLoader.html) instead of [FileResourceLoader](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/runtime/resource/loader/FileResourceLoader.html) for your Velocity. If you use it, you can simply call `VelocityEngine.getTemplate("template.vm")`.

Comment: What i am finding wierd, is why velocity execption throws : ResourceNotFoundException : Unable to find resource <Template Path>   When template path is prefixed with /   That's i think what cause the whole problem, cause the path is just right as i said : D:/FolderOne/FolderTwo/WEB-INF/classes/template.vm  but when prefixed with / it becomes : /D:/FolderOne/FolderTwo/WEB-INF/classes/template.vm   what makes the template unattainable and throws the exception

Comment: This is because [Class.getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) returns `URL`. [URL.getPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getPath()) does not do what you expect. It doesn't return file path. It returns path portion of the URL. Your URL is `file:///D:/FolderOne/FolderTwo/WEB-INF/classes/template.vm` and the path portion of the URL is `/D:/FolderOne/FolderTwo/WEB-INF/classes/template.vm`.